# Unit test Swift with third party library

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, localytics

I am using Localytics in my app which is basically just an API that can be used to send analytics data to the server.
https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#install-sdk-ios

I work in a project where we have to unit test every single file to make sure that there is atleast 90% code coverage.
 Since localytics is an external library, I have a wrapper around it to use the API. 
Consider the simple localytics method :

```
func tagScreen(screenName: String) {
    Localytics.tagScreen(screenName) 
}
```

How can I unit test this wrapper?
 Is there any suggestions?
How can we write Mocks for the method above?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the wrapper:
as `Localytics` has static functions to interact with I would go with something like:

```
class LocalyticsWrapper {
  private let tagFunc: (String) -> Void
  init(tagFunc: @escaping (String) -> Void = Localytics.tagScreen) {
    self.tagFunc = tagFunc
  }
  func tagScreen(screenName: String) {
    // maybe some pre-formatting done here or something
    tagFunc(screenName) 
  }
}
```

Now you can inject mock function and test the wrapper